# SQL Max(date) without group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

I have the following table...

```
MemberID  ServDate
001       12-12-2015
001       12-13-2015
001       12-15-2015
002       11-30-2015
002       12-04-2015
```

And I want to make it look like this...

```
MemberID  ServDate     LastServDate
001       12-12-2015   12-15-2015
001       12-13-2015   12-15-2015
001       12-15-2015   12-15-2015
002       11-30-2015   12-04-2015
002       12-04-2015   12-04-2015
```

Is there a way I can do this without having to use a `GROUP BY` or nested query? (I'm dealing with a very large database and the GROUP BY slows things down considerably)

Comment: maybe show us what query are you using and show us the `explain plan` so we can give you advice how improve the query

Comment: It's a SQL Server database.

Comment: something along the lines of...

Comment: You can use a correlated sub-query.

Comment: something along the lines of...    SELECT [MemberID],
  [ServDate],
  Max(ServDate) as [LastServDate]
  FROM [Table]A
  left join
  (SELECT [MemberID],
  Max(ServDate) as [LastServDate]
  FROM [Table]
  group by [MemberID])B
  on A.MemberID = B.MemberID

Comment: But I'm trying to do it in an easier way without having the join.

Comment: I think he's asking if there are any options besides a correlated query ("`nested`") query...

Comment: if there was something like... Max(ServDate) per MemberID, without having to group by.

Comment: Yes, the correlated query takes a very long time, and this is just one minor step in a much larger query.

Comment: "if there was something like... Max(ServDate) per MemberID, without having to group by." That's *exactly* what I posted 10 min. ago!

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT 
  MemberID, ServDate, 
  MAX(ServDate) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID) AS LastServDate
FROM Table
```

Standard SQL, so works in most modern RDBMS (including SQL Server and Oracle).

**EDIT** by the way, if you want to learn more: [MSDN ref. for OVER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)